# Change Numeric Values in Merge field to Indian Language (Marathi) in MailmergeWord

Tags: microsoft-word, language

I have a Mailmerge document with a series of text and numeric fields. I am wanting to do this document in Indian Language (Marathi). My excel fields are filled with all the text and numeric fields in Indian language (Marathi language).

When I mailmerge, everything displays ok except the numeric values are displayed in English.

Is there a way I can change the Display language of the mergefield to Marathi or simply display the numeric values in Marathi too ?

Marathi field in excel = १२,५०,४५०/-  >>>> displayed in Word as 12,50,450/-

Would appreciate any help !!

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that this isn't just an issue of font?

Comment: As Jeff correctly mentioned, the areas in which you are using numbers might have a different font applied. Please show a screenshot of the mentioned area and make sure to click into this area and also show the font dropdown, so that we can see what font is being used.

Comment: Cross-posted at: Word Forum https://www.msofficeforums.com/word/51524-display-numeric-values-indian-language-marathi-mailmerge.html
For cross-posting etiquette, please read: A Message to Forum Cross-Posters https://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Comment: TBH this area is a complete mess in Windows and Office. How are you achieving formats with Marathi/Devanagari in Excel? Are you typing using 1,2,3 etc. but using a Cell Format like [$-mr-IN,44E]0 , [$-mr-IN,439]0 to display the result as the equivalent Devanagari characters? If so, the underlying digits are still 0-9 and that's how they come through in Word. Although there are options in Word (File->Options->Advanced->Show Document Content->Numeral, none of the Options there seem to help even if you have the Marathi/Devanagari digits set up in Windows Regional formats.

Comment: That's assuming you have set the font that will be used to display the field results to be something that supports Marathi/Devanagari digits.But then even if you can get that to work, it will probably affect all numbers/numeric fields whether you formatted them as Marathi or otherwise in Excel. 

What *may* work is to add the Character Formatting switch \\*HINDIARABIC at the end of your field code - e.g. change { MERGEFIELD columnname } to { MERGEFIELD columnname \\*HINDIARABIC }. But I can't tell whether that will actually do what you need - perhaps try it and let us know.

Comment: Thanks Loeli & Jonsson for the response.

Comment: Jonsson, actually your suggestion of adding a switch \*HINDIARABIC worked very well. But when I add that, I loose my number formatting I had added to use comma separators as per Indian system i.e. it looked like this {MERGEFIELD\# 00','00','000} ...... is there a way  I can use these two switches simultaneously ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't see a simple way to do that. I thought imight be possible to do it by nesting fields, e.g. { QUOTE { MERGEFIELD columnname \\#0.00 } \\*HINDARABIC }, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Vik, what is the name of the font you are using?

Comment: @Loeli Yes, if you have a font where the Marathi characters for 0 to 9 are mapped to the code points U+0030 to U+0039 you only need format the field with that font and add \\*Charformat to the field. But do people have fonts mapped that way these days?

Comment: @Vik In the end if you can create new columns in your Excel data, perhaps use an Excel format to format the number exactly as you want it in the merge, then, in another column, use an Excel formula to replace 0-9 with with Devanagari codes. Then you have a text column that you could merge into Word as is. e.g. a formula like =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B3,"1","१"),"2","२"),"3","३"),"4","४"),"5","५"),"6","६"),"7","७"),"8","८"),"9","९"),"0","०").